# RabbitMQ nack-requeue function

Tags: rabbitmq

Take into account I have a large queue with X messages. Whenever a nack with requeue=True is made, it puts the message on top of X messages and redelivers to the same consumer, doing a bottleneck and not letting the other messages to be processed by the consumer.

Is there a way to put the message on the tail of the queue treating them as new, so if I have X messages, I could process them first before the requeued message?

Comment: What would you gain with this? I mean let's say you do put it at the end it eventually it will get to the consumer and the processing will fail again, wont it?

Comment: The other X messages can be processed instead of being waiting for processing.

Comment: Sure.I meant what happens when the message that was re-queued ends up being consumed again?

Comment: Well, it will fail again and be re-queued into the head of the list.

Comment: So basically, when it get to be consumed again it will be requeued again, and so to infinity and beyond. Meaning you should log it as error and ACK it.

Comment: In this case, it will be logged as error, but we don't want to lose the data until another consumer that knows how to process the message connects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this problem, I didn't want to ACK a message if there was an error and then lose it, I wanted to keep track of `unprocessed` messages.

I realized I could create another queue to save the unprocessed messages there and let the other messages flow!